# Python: pass "not" as a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I need to pass a function as a parameter that works as the boolean "not". I tried something like this but it didn't work because `not` isn't a function.

```
theFunction(callback=not) # Doesn't work :(
```

I need to do the following, but **I wonder if there exists any predefined function that does this simple job**, so that I don't have to redefine it like this:

```
theFunction(callback=lambda b: not b, anotherCallback=lambda b: not b)
```

---

***Note:*** I can't change the fact that I have to pass a function like this because it's an API call.

Comment: [**`operator.not_`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.not_)

Comment: Instead of your lambda example you could've still been mostly idiomatic with `def not_(b): return not b` and then `theFunction(callback=not_, anotherCallBack=not_)`.

Comment: What is this a duplicate of?

Comment: @PatrickCollins as always: see the banner at the top.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there is the `operator` module: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html

```
import operator
theFunction(callback=operator.not_)
```

Answer (score 14):

`not` is **not a function**, but a keyword. So that means you can not pass a reference. There are good reasons, since it allows Python to "*short circuit*" certain expressions.

You can however use the `not_` (with underscore) of the `operator` package:

```
from operator import not_

theFunction(callback=not_, anotherCallback=not_)
```